# What is the meaning of всё + comparative?

Tags: phrase

I've seen several instances of phrases in which всё precedes a comparative:

- Я бегу **всё выше**
- **всё бо́льше** и бо́льше
- Я **всё ещё** не сделал это

I read "всё" as meaning something like "still" in English, in these sentences. "Higher still", "more still", etc. Is this accurate? Does "всё" simply emphasize a comparative, or does it carry more subtle connotations? Can "всё" be used with any comparatives in this way, and could you give one or two more examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is closer to English "yet":

> Я бегу всё выше // I'm running yet higher up
>
> Всё больше и больше // Yet more and more
>
> Я всё ещё не сделал это // I haven't done it yet

In the last sentence, *всё* does not modify a comparative, though. It's a part of *всё ещё* which is a little bit more emphatic than mere *ещё*:

> — Сделал? — Ещё не сделал. — А теперь? — Всё ещё не сделал.

"Higher still" (like in "gas prices are high, but they were higher two years ago, and higher still three years ago") would correspond to Russian *ещё*:

> Бензин нынче дорог, но два года назад он был дороже, а три года назад — ещё дороже.

Comment: Yet = Still (often)

Answer (score 2):

In an informal context, I've always treated this as "more and more", or perhaps "increasingly" in a more formal context. With your examples:

1. I'm running higher and higher.
2. More and more

The last example is slightly different, but I certainly agree with Quassnoi♦'s translation.

Example from Brodsky: 


Теперь все чаще чувствую усталость,

все реже говорю о ней теперь

Now I am feeling exhausted more and more (frequently),

I am now speaking of it (the exhaustion) more and more rarely

(Please note that my translation above is hideously literal for a poem, but I kept it this way just to keep focus on все [comparative].)

Poem for reference: http://pishi-stihi.ru/teper-vse-chashhe-chuvstvuyu-ustalost-brodskij.html

Comment: In Brodsky's verse "Говорю о ней" = "Speak of it (weariness)", not "her".

Comment: @user4419802 Thank you for pointing out that careless mistake!

Answer (score 1):

The question of this topic already includes a full answer. Yes, if "всё" precedes a comparative then it means emphasizing like *still* or *yet*. This construction is quite common. Let's take a couple of examples from Russian poetry. (BTW. All poems are of "The Silver Age": much sophisticated, more fun to translate).

From Blok (The Twelve):

> *Всё быстрее и быстрее*
>   Уторапливает шаг.
>   Замотал платок на шее —
>   Не оправится никак...

From Mayakovsky (The conversation with the tax inspector about poetry):

> *Всё меньше* любится, *всё меньше* дерзается,
>   и лоб мой время с разбега крушит.
>   Приходит страшнейшая из амортизаций —
>   амортизация сердца и души.

From Mayakovsky (The flute-backbone):

> *Всё чаще* думаю -
>   не поставить ли лучше
>   точку пули в своем конце.
>   Сегодня я
>   на всякий случай
>   даю прощальный концерт.

From Esenin (I don't regret, don't call, don't cry):

> Дух бродяжий! ты *всё реже, реже*
>   Расшевеливаешь пламень уст.
>   О моя утраченная свежесть,
>   Буйство глаз и половодье чувств.

From Gumilev (Sahara):

> Так и будут бродить до скончанья веков,
>   Каждый час *всё грозней и грознее*,
>   Головой пропадая среди облаков,
>   Эти страшные серые змеи.

From Balmont (The Swan):

> И когда блеснули звёзды дальние,
>   И когда туман вставал в глуши,
>   Лебедь пел *всё тише*, *всё печальнее*,
>   И шептались камыши.

From Bryusov:

> Всё чаще
>
> Всё чаще по улицам Вильно
>   Мелькает траурный креп.
>   Жатва войны обильна,
>   Широк разверзнутый склеп.
>
> Всё чаще в темных костёлах,
>   В углу, без сил склонена,
>   Сидит, в мечтах невесёлых
>   Мать, сестра иль жена.
>
> Война, словно гром небесный,
>   Потрясает испуганный мир...
>   Но всё дремлет ребёнок чудесный,
>   Вильно патрон - Казимир.
>
> Всё тот же, как сон несказанный,
>   Как сон далеких веков,
>   Подымет собор святой Анны
>   Красоту точёных венцов.
>
> И море всё той же печали,
>   Всё тех же маленьких бед,
>   Шумит в еврейском квартале
>   Под гулы русских побед.